# Select last row of each group in PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks as follows:

| TS | Serial Number | Activity | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 |  | AAAABBBBCCCC |
| 2 | 123456 |  | AAAABBBBCCCC |
| 3 | 123456 | A | AAAABBBBCCCC |
| 4 | 123456 | E | AAAABBBBCCCC |
| 5 | 876543 | A | UNIUNIUNIUNI |
| 6 | 123456 | A | AAAABBBBCCCC |
| 7 | 123456 | E | WAHWAHWAHWAH |
| 8 | 123456 |  | WAHWAHWAHWAH |
| 9 | 876543 | E | ALFALFALFALF |
| 10 | 876543 |  | ALFALFALFALF |

`TS` is a timestamp column that usually contains an ISO date string. I've shortened this for simplicity.

As you can see, a change in the `Address` field CAN occur whenever there's an `Activity = E`.

Some further background about the data:

The ungrouped rows can be in semi-arbitrary order, though each Activity `A` within a group, when sorted by timestamp (`TS`), MUST always be followed by an Activity `E`, however not necessarily immediately. There CAN be `<null>` Activities in between the `A` and `E`. If there is no `E` following the last `A` within a group, sorted by `TS`, the corresponding `Serial Number` can safely be considered invalid.

What I need

For each `Serial Number`, sorted by `TS` in ascending order, I need the `Address` of the last occurrence of `Activity = E`, if and only if that last `E` is NOT followed by another `A`, otherwise `Address` may contain `INVALID` or alternatively the corresponding `Serial Number` can be omitted from the result.

Comment: It is appreciated and a good practice to add the desired output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=05d0e06e1adb4e3063cf17b00ed4c56c)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ser_no)         -- 4
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX(ts) FILTER (WHERE activity = 'A') OVER (PARTITION BY ser_no) as last_a,    -- 1
        MAX(ts) FILTER (WHERE activity = 'E') OVER (PARTITION BY ser_no) as last_e
    FROM
        mytable
) s
WHERE last_a < last_e               -- 2
    AND activity = 'E'              -- 3
ORDER BY ser_no, ts DESC            -- 4
```

1. Find timestamp of last `A` and last `E` using the [`MAX()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)
2. Choose only those `ser_no` partitions where last `A` was before last `E`
3. Remove all non-`E` records
4. Order remaining `E` records by timestamp `DESC`, to get the most recent the top-most record per group and remove all others using the `DISTINCT ON` claus

Comment: @HenrikWiese Do the answers help? If not, what should be changed. If they helped in any way: Please don't forget to UPVOTE (this honors the time the repliers invested into your problem with some internal points) and, if one solved the described problem completely, please ACCEPT this answer additionally to close the question. I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You need any "E" row not followed by any "A" or "E" with the same serial number.

This translates in SQL as:

```
SELECT Serial_Number, Address
FROM Tbl ret
WHERE Activity = 'E'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Tbl witness
    WHERE witness.Serial_Number = ret.Serial_Number
      AND witness.TS > ret.TS
      AND witness.Activity IN ('A', 'E')
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can use `distinct on` if you want to include the invalid records:

```
select ser_no, ts,
       (case when activity = 'E' then address
             else 'INVALID'
        end)
from t
where activity in ('E', 'A')
order by (ser_no, ts desc);
```

This just gets the last E/A row for each `ser_no` and assigns the address accordingly.

If you want to remove them, then you can still manage without a subquery.  It would be nice if Postgres had a "first"/"last" aggregation function, but you can mimic it with arrays:

```
select ser_no, max(ts),
       (array_agg(address order by ts desc))[1] as last_address
from t
where activity in ('E', 'A')
group by ser_no
having max(ts) filter (where activity = 'E') > max(ts) filter (where activity = 'A');
```

With a subquery, I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.activity = 'E' and
      t.ts = (select max(t2.ts)
              from t t2
              where t2.ser_no = t.ser_no and
                    t2.activity in ('A', 'E')
             );
```

This fetches the last "E" row when it is the last row for either E or A.